# pullback and push and the original set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In class, the prof says,

> Push and Pullback gives original set is smaller.
>
> Pull and Push back gives original set is bigger.

I don't understand its meaning...

$i.e$ he write something like this, 
\begin{align}
g (g^{-1} (B)) \subset B (?)
\end{align}

Can anyone gives detail explanation about above statements?

Comment: Have you tried proving those statements yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(g^{-1}(B))$ is the set of the images of the points whose image is in $B$. So it is in fact the set of the points of $B$, which are actually images of $f$, and so it is a subset of $B$.

$g^{-1}(g(A))$ is the set of the preimages of the images of points of $A$. So it is the set of the points which have the same image than a point of $A$, in particular, it contains the points of $A$...